# UIButton Not Hiding

Tags: ios, uibutton

I use IB and have properly wired up my buttons.  I have verified they are properly wired, as some IBAction methods will have buttons hide properly.  The issue I have is hiding the UIButtons when it first loads the app.  In viewDidLoad I set the button property to hidden, but it doesn't hide it.  Thoughts?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    stop.hidden = YES;
    play.hidden = YES;

    [activity startAnimating];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

After more debugging, the stop button hides but not the play.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your viewDidLoad code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell even from the code you posted why this is happening, The best guess will be that somewhere in the next lines of code you set it back to `visible = YES` mistakably. I would check if there is a method that shows the button that is called before it is needed.

**BUT**

If the initial state is hidden for your buttons. why don't you simply hide them on IB interface?

Comment: Had a leftover viewWillAppear line of code later on that set the hidden property to NO

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Remove outlet run the code ,test weather it works fine
- Remove outlet,add hidden property via IB and run it again and test if it is seen properly.

If it works fine the problem is with code written.

- Check the hidden property written via code